# How to replicate a function using mapply with multiple arguments to calculate the power of a method?

Tags: r, function, mapply, replicate

I have independent and dependent datasets. I want to test all possible relationships between dependent and independent variables and finally calculate the power of the method.

```
# dependent dataset
test_A <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nr=10, nc=10))
# independent dataset
test_B <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1,2), 500, replace = TRUE), nr=50, nc=10))
# Find all combination using dependent and independe datasets's variables
A_B_pair <- subset(expand.grid(c1=names(test_A), c2=names(test_B), 
                                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

# Main function to estimate the parameter and p-values 
test_function <- function(x,y){
  c1 <- test_A [[x]]
  c2 <- test_B[[y]]
  Data <- data.frame(1, XX=c1, YY=c2)
  
  model_lm <- lm(YY ~ XX, Data)
  est_lm <- as.numeric(model_lm$coefficients)[2]
  pvalue_lm <- as.numeric(summary(model_lm)$coeffi[,4][2])

  return(unlist(data.frame(lm.estimator = est_lm, lm.pvalue =pvalue_lm)))
}

# Using mapply  to get the all pairs estimators and p-values
output <- mapply(test_function, x=A_B_pair$c1, y=A_B_pair$c2)

# transpose the output
output.data <- data.frame(t(output))

# Put all the dependent and independent variables and their estimated values and p-values in a data frame.
output_final <- cbind(A_B_pair, output.data)
```

My problem is that I need to replicate this function 100 times to check the power of the method and estimate the parameters. Power would be calculated using the following command:

```
power <- mean(output_final$lm.pvalue <= 0.05)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try -

```
main_fn <- function() {
  test_A <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nr=10, nc=10))
  # independent dataset
  test_B <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1,2), 500, replace = TRUE), nr=50, nc=10))
  # Find all combination using dependent and independe datasets's variables
  A_B_pair <- subset(expand.grid(c1=names(test_A), c2=names(test_B), 
                                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  
  output <- mapply(function(x, y) test_function(test_A, test_B, x, y), 
                   A_B_pair$c1, A_B_pair$c2)
  output.data <- data.frame(t(output))
  output_final <- cbind(A_B_pair, output.data)
}

test_function <- function(test_A, test_B, x,y){
  c1 <- test_A[[x]]
  c2 <- test_B[[y]]
  Data <- data.frame(1, XX=c1, YY=c2)
  
  model_lm <- lm(YY ~ XX, Data)
  est_lm <- as.numeric(model_lm$coefficients)[2]
  pvalue_lm <- as.numeric(summary(model_lm)$coeffi[,4][2])
  
  return(unlist(data.frame(lm.estimator = est_lm, lm.pvalue =pvalue_lm)))
}

result <- do.call(rbind, replicate(100, main_fn(), simplify = FALSE))
power <- mean(result$lm.pvalue <= 0.05)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply@Ronak Shah.  The dimension of the final results is the number of replications and the dimension of the A_B_pair (For example, the result dataset produces 10000 x 4. But, I want to check the p-value for each pair of A_B_pair. Therefore,  I use the following code to get the desired output:                                      ```   ```cols <- c("c1", "c2"); final.results <- result %>%
  group_by_at(cols) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), list(mean)), .groups = 'drop');
power <- final.results$lm.pvalue_1 <= 0.5  ```

Comment: Hi @F. Privé, I want to use bigstatsr package to get the same results as my datasets are big. Could you please help me to apply the big_apple function to get the same results?

Comment: @DataScientist It seems that this question has been solved. If you want to add another component to it (large data), you should open a new question focusing on that.

Comment: @F.Privé, thank you. I have opened a new question regarding this question. Please see the question
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70080099/how-to-use-the-bigstatsr-r-package-using-two-datasets-for-estimating-the-paramet)