# How to use the bigstatsr R package using two datasets for estimating the parameters?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, bigdata, mapply, bigstatsr

I have independent and dependent datasets. I want to test all possible relationships between dependent and independent variables. In my previous post ([How to replicate a function using mapply with multiple arguments to calculate the power of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69869331/how-to-replicate-a-function-using-mapply-with-multiple-arguments-to-calculate-th/69869490?noredirect=1#comment123876126_69869490)), I wanted to do power analysis using simulation data. Now, I want to analyze real data using the same function. The problem is that the *test_function* needed more time as my dataset is big (dimension of each data set greater than 10000 X 40000). Also, I want to use parallel computing to speed up the calculation. I have found that the **bigstatsr** package (https://privefl.github.io/bigstatsr/index.html) can handle matrices that are too large to fit in memory. Moreover, I want to avoid *expand.grid* as it is also computationally expensive for big data. I did not find any post that can use two datasets simultaneously using the bigstatsr package and estimate parameters parallelly. Datasets examples and code are given below:

```
# dependent dataset
test_A <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nr=10, nc=10))
# independent dataset
test_B <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1,2), 500, replace = TRUE), nr=50, nc=10))
# Find all combination using dependent and independe datasets's variables
A_B_pair <- subset(expand.grid(c1=names(test_A), c2=names(test_B), 
                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
# Main function to estimate the parameter and p-values 
test_function <- function(test_A, test_B, x,y){
  c1 <- test_A [[x]]
  c2 <- test_B[[y]]
  Data <- data.frame(1, XX=c1, YY=c2)
  
  model_lm <- lm(YY ~ XX, Data)
  est_lm <- as.numeric(model_lm$coefficients)[2]
  pvalue_lm <- as.numeric(summary(model_lm)$coeffi[,4][2])
  
  return(unlist(data.frame(lm.estimator = est_lm, lm.pvalue =pvalue_lm)))
}
# Final output
output <- mapply(test_function, MoreArgs = list(test_A, test_B),
                 x = A_B_pair$c1, y = A_B_pair$c2)
```

**Edit:**
I want to apply my **proposed method** to estimate the parameters and compare the results with the *lm* method. My proposed method is given below:

```
library(pracma)
Proposed_method<- function(Data, Beta) 
{ 
  n = dim(Data)[1]
  Median <- t(apply(Data,2,median))
  Dist <- sqrt(rowSums((Data - as.matrix(rep(1,dim(Data)[1]))%*%Median)^2))
  Data0 <- as.matrix(Data[which(Dist <= as.numeric(quantile(Dist, p=.45, na.rm = TRUE))),])
  Yo <- as.matrix(Data0[,dim(Data0)[2]])
  Xo <- as.matrix(Data0[,-dim(Data0)[2]])
  Gama0 <- as.numeric(pinv(crossprod(Xo, Xo))%*%crossprod(Xo, Yo))
  Sigma2o <- var(Yo)
  Y <- as.matrix(Data[,dim(Data)[2]])
  X <- as.matrix(Data[,-dim(Data)[2]])
  
  DiffTol = 0.0001;
  DiffNorm = +10000;
  Iter = 0;
  ###########While loop################
  while (DiffNorm > DiffTol)
  {
    Const <- sqrt(2*pi*Sigma2o)
    devmat <- (Y-X%*%Gama0)
    Squaremat <- as.matrix(apply(devmat, c(1,2), function(x) x^2))
    Gauss <- exp(-Squaremat/(2*as.numeric(Sigma2o)))/as.numeric(Const)
    Wbeta <- exp(-(Beta*((Y-X%*%Gama0)*(Y-X%*%Gama0)))/(2*as.numeric(Sigma2o)))
    ONE1 <- rep(1,dim(X)[2]);
    Xb <- (X*(Wbeta%*%ONE1)) 
    Gama <- as.numeric(pinv(crossprod(X, Xb))%*%crossprod(Xb, Y)) 
    hedprod <- (Y-X%*%Gama)*(Y-X%*%Gama) 
    tWbeta <- as.matrix(t(Wbeta)) 
    One_1 <- as.matrix(rep(1,dim(X)[1])) 
    Sigma2 <- (tWbeta%*%hedprod)*pinv(tWbeta%*%One_1)
    
    LHb<-(sum(Gauss^Beta)/n-1)/Beta
    LH<-prod(Gauss)
    ##########
    Norm2 <- ((sum(Gama*Gama))^0.5 + abs(Sigma2))
    DiffNorm <-((sum((Gama-Gama0)*(Gama-Gama0)))^0.5 + abs(Sigma2 - Sigma2o))/Norm2
    ###
    Gama0 = Gama
    Sigma2o=Sigma2
    Iter = Iter + 1 
  }
  return(list(Gama=Gama,Sigma2=Sigma2,Wt=Wbeta,LHb=LHb,LH=LH))
}
# independent variable dataset
test_A <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1,2), 500, replace = TRUE), nr=10, nc=50))
# dependent variable dataset
test_B <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000), nr=10, nc=100))
# Find all combination using dependent and independe datasets's variables
A_B_pair <- subset(expand.grid(c1=names(test_A), c2=names(test_B), 
                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
# Main function to estimate the parameter and p-values by proposed method and lm 
test_function <- function(x, y){
  c1 <- test_A[[x]]
  c2 <- test_B[[y]]
  Data <- data.frame(1, XX=c1, YY=c2)
  nn <- dim(Data)[1]
  Beta = 0.1
  Omit = 2
  ResL1 <- Proposed_method(Data, Beta)
  ResL0 <- Proposed_method(as.matrix(Data[,-Omit]), Beta)
  LR0 <- (-nn)*log(ResL1$Sigma2/ResL0$Sigma2)
  
  # Proposed estimator
  Proposed_estimator <- (ResL1$Gama)[2]
  Proposed_pvalue <- as.numeric(pchisq(q=LR0, df=1, lower.tail = FALSE))
  
  #lm model
  model_lm <- lm(YY ~ XX, Data)
  est_lm <- as.numeric(model_lm$coefficients)[2]
  pvalue_lm <- as.numeric(summary(model_lm)$coeffi[,4][2])
  
  return(unlist(data.frame(lm.estimator = est_lm, lm.pvalue =pvalue_lm, Proposed_estimator,Proposed_pvalue)))
}

# Output:
output <- mapply(test_function, x = A_B_pair$c1, y = A_B_pair$c2)
# transpose the output
output_t <- data.frame(t(output))

# Final output
output_final <- cbind(A_B_pair, output_t)
output_final <- structure(list(c1 = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), c2 = c("X1", 
"X1", "X1", "X1", "X1"), lm.estimator = c(-0.855708052636761, 
0.227250280548332, -0.128955946232531, 0.171650221327542, -0.701027831473379
), lm.pvalue = c(0.0361141129937136, 0.646905371365762, 0.816730073250761, 
0.780290676037238, 0.261013977519426), Proposed_estimator = c(-0.879232513006948, 
0.242368232504351, -0.110999951753211, 0.174574390311335, -0.76456493319124
), Proposed_pvalue = c(0.0131801103443272, 0.583155149115837, 
0.870570103632653, 0.783460676404866, 0.154142429946211)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame"))
```

How can I apply bigstatsr and parallelly compute this function to get the outputs? Thank you so much for your effort and help.

Comment: `test_A` and  `test_B` should have the same number of rows, right?

Comment: @F. Privé, Yes, the row number should be the same for test_A and test_B datasets

Comment: I still don't think you have a problem of memory here. You can always transform `test_A` and `test_B` to some FBM so that you don't need to copy the data when using parallelization. But other from that, you should try to optimize your code so that it runs faster.

Comment: I have tried to use big_apply instead of `mapply` but it's not working. Could you please help me to optimize my code and apply bigstatsr for my function to get the desired outputs? Thank you for your effort.@F.Privé

Comment: You don't need big_apply here, you can just loop through the variables of the two datasets. Sorry, but I don't have time to benchmark and make your code faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is really a problem of size here (memory-wise), but just a computation time problem.

I think you just want to do some univariate testing. For that, you can use function `big_univLinReg`:

```
library(bigstatsr)
X <- as_FBM(test_B)
NCORES <- nb_cores()

k <- 1  ## replace by loop here
stats <- big_univLinReg(X, test_A[[k]], ncores = NCORES)
pval <- predict(stats, log10 = FALSE)
```

This function should be quite fast, and gives you all the coefficients for all variables in `test_B`. Then you only need to loop over the variables in `test_A`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply@F. Privé. I want to use my own function instead of the `lm` function to estimate the parameter and p-value. Also, I want to add two columns to the output dataset. One is the names of test_A and another is the names of the test_B dataset.

Comment: Output will be like this:  `output_t <- data.frame(t(output));
output_final <- cbind(A_B_pair, output_t); final_output <- structure(list(c1 = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), c2 = c("X1", 
"X1", "X1", "X1", "X1"), lm.estimator = c(-0.0422342260166708, 
-0.0187980183564189, 0.192428884676606, -0.0257373964876148, 
0.0673635213446617), lm.pvalue = c(0.701851660233888, 0.876046574990813, 
0.0962188742808562, 0.817364911991616, 0.54800706638316)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Please edit your question to have something closer to what you actually want to do then.

Comment: Dear @F. Privé, I have added a part in my question named "Edit". Please see this now and give your kind suggestion to adapt the code by applying bigstatsr.